# Totally remove spam/junk control from Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird

I want to totally remove (not train or anything, really remove or disable) the spam filtering from Thunderbird. How could I do that ?

I've seen very old similar questions without answers, so I'm asking again in case there's a solution in a recent version of Thunderbird. Of course the obvious solution (disabling adaptive junk mail controls for the local folder and the account) doesn't work.

[image]

My version : Thunderbird 24.3 / Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

That folder is also where messages marked by Gmail with the `spam` tag are shown.

If your using IMAP to access the messages you can turn off the visibility of the `spam` tag/folder. The setting is the the Gmail web interface.

[image]

Comment: What you mean is that the problem is in gmail filtering, not in Thunderbird ? Makes sense. Gmail settings aren't clearer than Thunderbird ones but I changed them and I'll see how it turns. If it works I'll go back and accept your answer.

Comment: I try [this manipulation](http://www.mydigitallife.info/how-to-disable-and-deactivate-spam-filter-protection-in-gmail-or-google-mail/).